# Como contar linhas de uma tabela com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando obter o número de linhas de um `Select` para mostrar ou não algumas mensagens ao usuário, mas todas as tentativas possíveis não me retornaram o resultado correto.
O que estou usando é uma classe do William Francisco Leite que me atende perfeitamente, mas não consigo o total de linhas como desejado.

O que tenho é isso aqui:

```
// CONEXÃO PDO   
$pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
$crud = Crud::getInstance($pdo, 'cadDolar');
```

O código da busca:

```
$sqlMaxDolar = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(Data),'%Y-%m-%d') as DataDolar FROM cadDolar";
$arrayParam = array();
$ResMaxDolar = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sqlMaxDolar, $arrayParam, TRUE);
$QtdeMaxDolar = count($ResMaxDolar);
```

Conforme sugestão:

```
print_r($ResMaxDolar);
Resultado: Array ( )
```

O resultado dessa consulta deveria ser 1 mas está me retornando 0.

Já tentei com o `rowCount`, mas o próprio manual diz que não é confiável utilizar .

Comment: Deu um print_r(ResMaxDolar); para verificar se esta localizando algum registro do banco de dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformar o resultado em array e dar um count é uma alternativa

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll();
count($result);
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php